# Using semaphore to wait for availability of all instances of a resource

Tags: c#, multithreading, semaphore

In a system I am building, there are two kinds of users - A and B - that can use resource R, of which there are n instances available.
Users requiring R keep piling up in their respective queues.

Constraints on allocation:

1. When m (m < n) instances are currently in use by users of one type, say A, the remaining (m-n) free instances cannot be used by waiting users of type B (and vice versa). When As are using R, Bs will have to wait for all As to release R before they start using R.
2. When m (m < n) instances are currently in use by users of one type, say A, the remaining (m-n) free instances can be allocated to waiting users of type A
   as long as it is ensured that there is no starvation of Bs. ie, the system should not keep the Bs waiting indefinitely because As are currently using R and more As keep piling up. It should flip over to allocate resources to B if Bs have been waiting for R beyond a system defined threshold interval.

I am trying to use a semaphore to co-ordinate the allocation of R to users.
Constraint 1 does not appear to be directly supported by Semaphore.

To achieve this, I am thinking of doing the following:

```
while(semaphore.CurrentCount < n)
    semaphore.Wait();
```

Is there a better way?

I see that SemaphoreSlim has a method Release(int32) that allows for release of more than one resource.

I would have expected Wait(int32) to allow waiting for the specificied count of instances to become available.
However, Wait(int32) API provided has a different purpose - the int32 argument here specifies timeout on the wait operation.

Isn't the asymmetry between the semantics of corresponding Wait() and Release() APIs a design flaw?
Is there some other API that SemaphoreSlim exposes which serves my purpose?

I considered using CountDownEvent instead, but I would need Semaphore anyway for the other constraint. Using the two in conjunction
sounds awkward. I am trying to make do with Semaphore alone.

Comment: Can you elaporated more on "it is ensured that there is no starvation of users of type B"?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Edited above with elaboration

Comment: You can't do Wait(n) atomically without locking. Your `while` sure loop looks nice and simple but it's not thread safe. Your requirements are quite complex, so you'll have to roll your own synchronisation as no out-of-the-box primitives will get you exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks Kirill...actually the entire method which has this code runs under a lock...thanks for bringing it up though